# Why is there no solution to the equation about A.P.?

Tags: equation-solving

Arithmetic progression a [n], s [n] is the sum of its first n terms. Known

```
a[1] + a[2] == 7, a[m] + a[m - 1] == 73, s[m] == 2020, m >= 3
```

Find their values

```
{a[1], d, m}
```

Why can't we obtain a result through the following calculation?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := 
 n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {a[1] + a[2] == 7, a[m] + a[m - 1] == 73, 
  s[m] == 2020, m >= 3};
 var = First@Solve[eqn, {a[1], d, m}]
```

```
Clear["Global`*"]
First@Solve[{2 a + 4 d == -16, 9 (a + 4 d) == -36, t == a + (n - 1) d,
    s == a n + n (n - 1)/2 d}, {t, s}, {a, d}]
```

```
Clear["Global`*"]
a[n_ /; n > 1] := a[1] + (n - 1) d; 
s[n_] := 
 n (a[1] + a[n])/2; eqn = {a[1] + a[5] == -16, s[9] == -36}; var = 
 First@FindInstance[eqn, {a[1], d}]
a[1] + (n - 1) d /. var // FullSimplify
a[n_] := %
n a[1] + n (n - 1)/2 d /. var // Simplify
s[n_] := %
```

Comment: If you evaluate all the lines you have written except for the final one that begins with `var` and then you evaluate `eqn`, what do you get?

Comment: `Solve` is not designed to solve to obtain the function `a`, which it needs to know in order to solve for the argument `m` in `a[m]` (also `a[-1+m]`).  The definition of `a` plays no role, because `a[m]` stays `a[m]`. It is difficult sometimes to keep clear what is coding and what is mathematics in Mathematica. Function definitions are not applied by solvers to expressions which do not match the defined patterns. Solvers that do solve for functions, like `DSolve` and `RSolve`, use equations to define functional relationships.

Comment: Please do not keep creating questions, deleting them, then posting minor variations on the same question. Your last four questions have all been very similar and have scored very poorly or closed because of basic mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a[1] = a1;
a[n_] := a[1] + (n - 1) d;
s[n_] := n (a[1] + a[n])/2
eqns = {
   a[1] + a[2] == 7,
   a[m] + a[m - 1] == 73,
   s[m] == 2020,
   m >= 3
   };
FindInstance[eqns, {a1, d, m}]

(** {{a1 -> 10/3, d -> 1/3, m -> 101}} **)
```

Comment: ```Clear["Global`*"]
a[1] = a1;
a[n_] := a[1] + (n - 1) d;
s[n_] := n (a[1] + a[n])/2
eqns = {a[1] + a[2] == 7, a[m] + a[m - 1] == 73, s[m] == 2020, m >= 3};
var = First@FindInstance[eqns, {a1, d, m}]
a[1] + (n - 1) d /. var // FullSimplify
n a[1] + n (n - 1)/2 d /. var // Simplify```

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
First@Solve[{2 a + 4 d == -16, 9 (a + 4 d) == -36, t == a + (n - 1) d,
    s == a n + n (n - 1)/2 d}, {t, s}, {a, d}]
```

```
{t -> 2 (-7 + n), s -> -13 n + n^2}
```